# Increasing States in Tsetlin Automata

Tags: artificial-intelligence, automata

What is the effect of increasing number of states in Tsetlin Automatas? Will both learning speed and accuracy increase?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your asking, but it doesn't look like it is directly related to programming, therefor it is off topic.

Comment: @09stephenb how is this not directly related to programming? I guess it counts as a performance question regarding a specific type of algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning speed will decrease, while accuracy will increase.